# get just HH:MM on batch script

Tags: batch-file, time

I need to get just HH:MM to the code work but if I do `echo %TIME%`  the variable is HH:MM:SS, how can I break the string or make it show just hours and minutes?

Comment: TBF, the question seems to be more about variable expansion than how to get the date and time in a specific format, _(although getting a known consistent format should be essential as part of the task)_. I have therefore provided an answer which achieves both the consistent format and the required expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %TIME:~0,-3%
```

Although %time% for me shows `22:23:01.87`

so for me,

```
echo %TIME:~0,-6%
```

See `set /?` from the prompt for more info.

Comment: thank u, ur answere helped me so much

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue with your idea is that `%TIME%` is not output in a consistent format accross locales, PC's, or users. If you want a method which should work regardless of PC or User settings, then the following may help you:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=2-3 Delims=: " %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" \: . /NJH /L | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" " 123""') Do @Echo %%G:%%H
```

You may be better advised to use the same method to save new variables with the current date and time in a known format first, i.e. `yyyy/MM/dd` and `hh:mm:ss`, then use variable expansion on the time one to either the first five characters `~,5`, or the everything except for the last three, `~,-3`.

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" \: . /NJH /L | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" " 123""'
) Do @Set "NowDate=%%G" & Set "NowTime=%%H"
@Set Now & Echo hh:mm is %NowTime:~,5% & Pause
```

*The last line is just included to provide you with example output, you would obviously change that to suit your own purposes.*